# remove object property inside of object

Tags: javascript

I have an object of object

```
 cart {
  KDR010011: {
    barcode: "0"
    brand: "Kapal Api"
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR"
    cost_price: "107569.66490299824"
    cost_price_per_piece: 896.413874191652
    name: "Kapal Api 25g sp mix"
    product_id: "KDR010011"
    qty: 1
    qty_per_box: 120
    selling_price: 116000
    selling_price_per_piece: 962.5
  },
  KDR010125: {
    barcode: ""
    brand: "Kapal Api"
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR"
    cost_price: "110317.63859070961"
    cost_price_per_piece: 835.7396862932546
    name: "ABC Susu 31g"
    product_id: "KDR010125"
    qty: 5
    qty_per_box: 132
    selling_price: 113000
    selling_price_per_piece: 863.6363636363636
  }
}
```

and I want to remove the property, the result what I want:

```
cart {
  KDR010011: {
    qty: 1
    selling_price: 116000
  },
  KDR010125: {
    qty: 5
    selling_price: 113000
  }
}
```

I am using [underscore js library](https://underscorejs.org/#omit), the result is this:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please try something and share it if you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily by looping over the keys of the object and assigning the value for each key back to the original object. If you don't want to modify the original object just assign the keys to a new one.

Personally I'd change my data structure so that the cart was an array of objects and each object had the `KDR010011` key as a property instead.

```js
const obj = {
  KDR010011: {
    barcode: "0",
    brand: "Kapal Api",
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR",
    cost_price: "107569.66490299824",
    cost_price_per_piece: 896.413874191652,
    name: "Kapal Api 25g sp mix",
    product_id: "KDR010011",
    qty: 1,
    qty_per_box: 120,
    selling_price: 116000,
    selling_price_per_piece: 962.5,
  },
  KDR010125: {
    barcode: "",
    brand: "Kapal Api",
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR",
    cost_price: "110317.63859070961",
    cost_price_per_piece: 835.7396862932546,
    name: "ABC Susu 31g",
    product_id: "KDR010125",
    qty: 5,
    qty_per_box: 132,
    selling_price: 113000,
    selling_price_per_piece: 863.6363636363636,
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = {
  qty: obj[key].qty,
  selling_price: obj[key].selling_price,
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I have a very strong feeling we could use destructuring somehow. `{qty,selling_price} = cart`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const newCart = {...cart}
Object.keys(newCart).forEach(key => {
  newCart[key] = {
    qty: newCart[key].qti,
    selling_price: newCart[key].sailing_price
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the overhead of an object copy? Just use the original object and assign to a new empty object if you don't want to overwrite the original.

Comment: @JamesCoyle, it depends on OP requirememnts, if he doesnt want to copy he can reassign 
cart = newCart

Comment: There is absolutely no need to copy though. Just use the existing object to build the new data and assign that to a new empty object. The copy achieves nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You need commas in your object

I have a feeling I could use destructuring better than here

```js
const cart = {
  KDR010011: {
    barcode: "0",
    brand: "Kapal Api",
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR",
    cost_price: "107569.66490299824",
    cost_price_per_piece: 896.413874191652,
    name: "Kapal Api 25g sp mix",
    product_id: "KDR010011",
    qty: 1,
    qty_per_box: 120,
    selling_price: 116000,
    selling_price_per_piece: 962.5
  },
  KDR010125: {
    barcode: "",
    brand: "Kapal Api",
    category: "KEBUTUHAN DAPUR",
    cost_price: "110317.63859070961",
    cost_price_per_piece: 835.7396862932546,
    name: "ABC Susu 31g",
    product_id: "KDR010125",
    qty: 5,
    qty_per_box: 132,
    selling_price: 113000,
    selling_price_per_piece: 863.6363636363636
  }
}

let newCart = {}
Object.keys(cart).forEach(key => newCart[key] = { qty: cart[key].qty, selling_price : cart[key].selling_price })
console.log(newCart)
```